# Не работает метод write.string(*str) в rapidjson, как решить?

Tags: c++, json

На вход в json передаю `vector<string>vecs`, но выдает ошибку(коммит в конце), помогите решить..

```
        std::vector<string>::iterator itm;
        for(itm = vecs.begin(); itm != vecs.end(); ++itm)
        {
            writer.String(*itm);
        }
        writer.EndArray();
        writer.EndObject();

        std::string fullJsonString = sb.GetString();
```

Ошибка в строке writer.string(*itm):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson:‌​:UTF8<> >
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? Где? Какой коммит?

Comment: исправил, комментарий обрезался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
writer.String((*itm).c_str());
```